# Is there anywhere I can find information on the relative popularity of Perl modules?

Tags: perl, cpan, perl-module, popularity

One of the problems of using CPAN is that "there's more than one module to do it". I often wonder what everyone else is using.

Is there any information on the relative popularity of CPAN modules anywhere?

Comment: I'm thinking probably no, at least not via CPAN; from the horse's mouth: http://www.cpan.org/misc/cpan-faq.html#Plans_for_statistics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in download counts, some numbers are available on [PPM Index](http://code.activestate.com/ppm/) - look for popular modules. Data are a bit skewed, since it is Windows only, but you can get an idea.

Answer (score 10):

[Recommended CPAN Modules](https://www.socialtext.net/perl5/recommended_cpan_modules)

Update: Here are other discussions on the topic from PerlMonks:

[Social CPAN : Finding the best and most popular modules](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=737447)

[cpan module; download count](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=725087)

[How to pick a CPAN module](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=720773)

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~apeiron/Task-Kensho-0.28/lib/Task/Kensho.pm is a good recommended list, if you want to go that way, with some sound policy/philosophy behind it.

Answer (score 3):

When it works, [CPANTS](http://cpants.perl.org/) has a feature that counts the number of times a module on CPAN is used by other modules on CPAN.

Answer (score 1):

[Task::Kensho](http://search.cpan.org/~apeiron/Task-Kensho-0.28/lib/Task/Kensho.pm) is usually where I start.  Its an actively maintained list of recommended modules and its on a monthly release schedule.  The group of people maintaining it seem fairly [organized](http://www.enlightenedperl.org/) and are very active in the community so I think it is a pretty accurate reflection of whats currently considered "good" in the Perl community.

Obviously it doesn't cover every possible topic and the whole thing is at least somewhat subjective, but I still think its useful.

Answer (score 1):

MetaCPAN has a favorite database for CPAN distributions.

The list of the most popular CPAN modules according to this database can be seen here: https://metacpan.org/favorite/leaderboard

Answer (score 0):

I use to perform google site search on the stackoverflow several times : 
site:http://stackoverflow.com perl <> ... quick browse of the first 10 results gives me an idea on whether or not the module would be worth enough to try ...